# How to show live attributes when hovering in map

Tags: javascript, attributes, hover, openlayers

i'm still new in openlayers. i would like to show "location" attribute on right corner of the map when hover in map. my map consist of of many attributes and one of them is location. how can i possibly do this. is Openlayers capable of doing this? the example is in http://index.gain.org when we hover on the map we can see the country on top right of the map. appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/feature-events.html), which display feature’s attributes on hover.